# highcharts half pie container too big

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a half pie chart but I want the container to act as if its a half-pie chart rather than acting like a full pie that's hiding half. What I mean by this is I don't want the container to be big enough to hold the full pie, just the half. I would then put a custom legend underneath. Here is what I am seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/dangeruponu/bk2E5/

[image: example]

Here are my options:

```
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            width: 400,
            height: 400
        },
        title: {
            text: 
                '<div style="padding: 10px; color: white; background-color: #000000">' +
                    '<span style="font-size: xx-large">11</span><br/>' +
                    '<span>Total</span>' +
                '</div>',
            floating: true,
            useHTML: true,
            y: 100
        },
        legend: {
            symbolHeight: 0,
            symbolWidth: 0,
            floating: true,
            useHTML: true,
            labelFormat: '<div style="width: 80px; background-color: {color}; text-align: center; border: 2px solid"><span>{name}</span><br/><span style="font-size: larger">{y}</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.name}: {point.y}',
            headerFormat: ''
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                events: {
                    click: function(event){
                        scope.$apply(urlService.url(event.point.page));                                 
                    }
                },
                selected: false,
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                innerSize: '90%',
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            data: [
                {
                    name: 'Re-work',
                    y: 4,
                    page: '',
                    color: '#7CB5EC'
                },
                {
                    name: 'New',
                    y: 2,
                    page: 'NEW',
                    color: '#995CAC'
                },
                {
                    name: 'In-progress',
                    y: 5,
                    page: '/orders/in_progress',
                    color: '#90ED7D'
                }
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

I realize I could move the center down but then I would have a big block of space at the top. Is it possible to adjust the container separate from the chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertical center of a pie is 50% by default. So when you only show the top half, you should adjust the center down. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.center. The `size` option also probably needs setting.

Comment: And example for it: http://jsfiddle.net/bk2E5/4/ I suggest to set: `size: 350`, `center: ['50%', '80%']` and `innerSize: 300`.

Comment: This is perfect thanks. I had tried moving the center, but I was missing the size.

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting the height first:

```
         height: 250
```

Comment: I tried setting the height, but the graph size changes to the smallest height or width.

Answer (score 0):

you can move up the legend.

`y:-100,`

this will send the legend 100px up occupying that unwanted space.

updated your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bk2E5/3/)

I hope this will be of some use for you

Comment: This helps the eye-sore, but now all the space has just moved underneath. The idea here is to have it as a widget so I'm trying to get rid of unused space. Thanks for the response though.